# how is collection_select processed in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections, drop-down-menu, process

I made a drop down list using collection_select

```
<%= collection_select(:page, :user_id, @users, :id, :full_name) %>
```

that part works fine.  I am having trouble on saving it/processing it using the controller, the APIdock isn't very helpful on that part and I haven't been able to get the one example I found to work.  Can anyone explain to me how I can process the selected value in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a value

```
params[:page][:user_id]
```

which will correspond to the value selected in the form. You can see it inspecting the `params` variable.

IT is a number, the ID of the selected user. You could load the user by

```
@user = User.find(params[:page][:user_id])
```

but it's useless. In fact, if the `user_id` property of the page is accessible, then with the usual

```
@page.update_attributes(params[:page]) # in the update action
```

or

```
@page.create(params[:page]) # in the create action
```

you will get the user in the page as `@page.user`.

Comment: how would I use this to find a preexisting object?  I've tried @ user = params[:page][:user_id] then @page = Page.find(@ user) as well as @ page = params[:page][:user_id] then @ user = User.find(@ user) but they don't work, they havn't thrown any errors but at the same time they don't return any values.

Comment: please post the opening part of the "select" tag (to see the name), and inspect also `params` ("`pp params`" at the start of the controller, check the rails console for the output, it's a hash).

Comment: <div class="field">
   <select id="page_user_id" name="page[user_id]"><option value="1">kan</option>
<option value="2">admin1</option>
<option value="3">root</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">admin</option>

<option value="5">user</option>

<option value="6">admin2</option>

<option value="7">routeadmin</option></select>

  </div> that's the html code that is generated, I assume that's what you mean by the select tag, as for inspecting params I tried using params[:page][:user_id].inspect and that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To store page values in model which should specify '**has_many :pages**' in user.rb.

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@user.pages = params[:page]
```

params[:page] returns an array of values which will be store in current model record.

Comment: thanks, how would you modify this so you would be able to modify an existing record though instead of creating a new one?